# How to autowire @service from external Jar in Spring

Tags: spring, service, jar, autowired, maven-war-plugin

I am developing two spring based application(Ex app1 and app2) fully on Java configuration with Maven and no XML config.
Through Maven -WAR plugin , I have created Jar reference of app2 and using `mvn install:install file` I have binded the app2 jar with app1.
app2 - Its used to fetch inforamtion from data source.

I have autowired the app2 serive in app1 implementation class to fetch the details which was annotated with `@Service` in app2 application.

My first doubt is:

Both app1 and app2 have separate AppConfig.java file.Is it possible to simply autowiring one of the `@Service` which is availble in Jar format or else I need to define or import App2's AppConfig java file into App1's AppConfig.jave file.

I have tried with the simple autowired the external JAR `@Service` class and ended with error.

Kindly help me on what needs to be done to autowire external Jar's `@Service` to the 
implementation class.

Below is my App1 repository class

```
@Repository
public class VehicleRepository {   

    @Autowired  
    VehicleService vehicleservice;   

    public Map<String, item> getAllTypes(String type) {     

            Vehicke vehicle = vehicleservice.getAllVehicle(type);

            // handle response here...
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // handle exception here
        } finally {

        }
        return vehicleDetails;
    }

}
```

`VehicleService` is available in external Jar.

VehicleService Class:

```
@Service
public class VehicleService {

    public VehicleService() {
    }

    @Autowired
    PortRepository portRepository;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;


    public Vehicle getAllVehicles(String type) {
        List<Vehicle> cehicles = portRepository.getPorts();
        return vehicle;
    }
```

Comment: Beans are defined by a configuration class. If Spring is not initialized with one of the config classes, then obviously the beans defined by this config class are not known to Spring.

Comment: @JBNizet Is there any way to call App2's config before autowire service in the repository class or How to call/Include  App2's AppConfig file to App1's Appcofig

Comment: By importing App2's config class from App1's config class: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html. But if those are really applications, designed to be run independantly, you'll certainly have conflicting beans. You'll probably have to write a seperate config class to load only the beans from App2 that make sense when used as part of App1.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it simple. 
Your App1 depends on App2. 
So you use *@Import(App2Config.class) class App1Config {}*, that's it.

And by the way, instead of tricks with '*mvn install:install file*' you can just use parent pom.xml with modules app1 and app2, and declare dependency of module app1 on module app2 in pom.xml <dependencies> section. You then run '*mvn install*' to build your project. 
See an example here: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: When I use Import of another App config and created WAR deployed in Tomcat but I got below errror "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to register servlet with name 'dispatcher'.Check if there is another servlet registered under th
e same name."

Comment: One more doubt .Is it simple Import is enough or I need to autowire and define what are the definition available in App2 config into App1 config

Comment: Regarding the first comment: you should have only one web.xml file in which you define only a single servlet with the given name. Regarding the second comment: @Import causes your App1Config to include all beans defined in App2Config, as if they were defined there.