# How to autowire a component in a dependency/external jar in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project and I can't get components from an **external jar** to be autowired. When I try to, I got a `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` saying that can't find a bean with that name available.

I tried some solutions found in similar questions, like these ones:

[How to autowire @service from external Jar in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451192/how-to-autowire-service-from-external-jar-in-spring)

[Spring Boot @autowired does not work, classes in different package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367316/spring-boot-autowired-does-not-work-classes-in-different-package)

[How can I @Autowire a spring bean that was created from an external jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571304/how-can-i-autowire-a-spring-bean-that-was-created-from-an-external-jar)

..but still can't managed it to work.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Here is **boot class** in the Spring Boot project **spring-project-example**

```
package com.springdi.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.dependency.example.DependencyBasePackageClass;
import com.dependency.example.somepackage.SomeBean;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springdi.example"}, basePackageClasses = DependencyBasePackageClass.class)
public class SpringProjectExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringProjectExampleApplication.class, args);

        String beanName = SomeBean.class.getName();
        System.out.printf("%s can be autowired: %s\n", beanName, String.valueOf(context.containsBean(beanName)).toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

It's just a simple Spring Boot project checking if it is possible to autowire a component present in the dependency jar.

Here is the **component** in the **jar** (dependency-example-1.0.0.jar)

```
package com.dependency.example.somepackage;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeBean {

    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Some process...");
    }
}
```

And here is the **base package class** of this same **jar**

```
package com.dependency.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Just a class to serve as the root for component
 * scanning in "com.dependency.example" and its sub-packages
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DependencyBasePackageClass {

}
```

I've already tried `@Import(DependencyBasePackageClass.class)` in SpringProjectExampleApplication and `@ComponentScan` with `basePackages` and `basePackageClasses`, but no success.

I also tried using `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {SpringProjectExampleApplication.class, DependencyBasePackageClass.class})`

and the not type safe `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.springdi.example", "com.dependency.example"})`.

`@Configuration @ComponentScan({"com.dependency.example"})` also fails, `context.containsBean("com.dependency.example.somepackage.SomeBean")` still returns **false**.

This jar is included in classpath and in the pom.xml as a dependency

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- other dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rbaggio</groupId>
        <artifactId>dependency-example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dependency-example-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Could it be the location of the jar, the way it is included or some extra configuration needed?

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is hindering in finding that dependent bean. Do `@Import` or create a bean that returns the dependent project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okey some basic things, you have mixed up your packages a bit.

`@SpringBootApplication` will scan all classes in packages below the class this is annotated on. This annotation is an alias for `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` means that `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springdi.example"}, basePackageClasses = DependencyBasePackageClass.class)` is **not needed**.

```
com.springdi.example     // class with @SpringBootApplication annotation
         |
         |
         |
com.springdi.example.*    // Will find all @Service, @Component, @Configuration
                          // in subpackages below the @SpringBootApplication 
                          // annotation
```

You can read more about the annotation here [SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation)

Since your other annotated classes are **NOT** in the same package structure as the `@SpringBootApplication` you need to define all the places you want to scan for annotations.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.springdi.example", "com.dependency.example"})
```

will probably include all the packages that you want to scan through.

Comment: I've tried this too, but no success... applicationContext.containsBean("com.dependency.example.somepackage.SomeBean") still returns false. I think the problem can be the way the jar is included in classpath or some missing annotation. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: you need to remove the second `@ComponentScan` in your DependencyBasePackageClass

Comment: Still doesn't work.. but if I give a name to SomeBean like @Component("someBean") somehow it works. It seems that I'll have to name every single bean in the included jars in order to make use of them with @Autowired

Comment: if you skip the package name when asking for the bean. applicationContext.containsBean("someBean")

Comment: you can use this to list all loaded beans
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348937/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded-spring-boot

Comment: It also works. And listing all loaded beans will be helpful. Thank you Thomas! (I'll be accepting your answer above)

Comment: perfect, this is what I needed, I do have to ask the question is a bad practice design wise to have beans in external libraries?

Comment: @Snedden27 nothing mentioned from the spring boot team. But usually if you want to write a library that gets loaded with spring boot is to write a "spring boot starter" that will load in the needed beans during some specific conditions

Comment: For me it is not working. Can someone upload example POC to github or something. that would help me alot to find the missing/wrong pieces that i am doing